# Running appium scripts for ios in parallel

Tags: ios, macos, appium, selenium-grid

I have two mac machines with all the setup installed for appium. I want to run the appium scripts on two ios simulators in parallel.It is not possible in one mac machine by launching two simulators in parallel because mac uses only one instrument instance at a time.

Is there any way to approach this by using two machines?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For android you can run two emulators in parallel, So u can establish two appium sessions and run the scripts in parallel.But coming to ios xcode won't allow you to run the simulators in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Selenium grid to handle your two machines, as instructed at https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/advanced-concepts/grid.md

Otherwise you'll need to create a driver session against each of the servers in your script. To target a specific Appium server, simply change the url:port combination to match either of your servers when creating the Appium webdriver object/session.

Answer (score 0):

As of now,
http://appium.io/docs/en/advanced-concepts/parallel-tests/
"With Xcode9 Appium supports parallel RealDevice and Simulator testing." for iOS

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).